# Big difference in time taken to perform graph queries

Tags: arangodb, aql

Based on the following collections:

```
data_invoices (document, 100,000 total records, 2 tenants)
    hash: tenantId
    persistent: createdOn

data_jobs (document, 10,000 total records, 2 tenants)
    hash: tenantId
    persistent: createdOn

data_links (edge, 100,000 total records)
    persistent: createdOn
    persistent (sparse): replacedOn
```

The links collection will connect one invoice to a random job, so a job may have zero or more invoices.  An invoice should have one or more jobs, but in my data, each invoice is matched to only one job.  The `date` filter does not actually filter out any data (they are all less than the specified date value) and neither does the `tenantId` filter since all the data is either `xxx` or `yyy`.

The generic structure of data_jobs and data_invoices is:

```
tenantId: string;
createdOn: number;
data: [{
    createdOn: number;
    values: {
        ...collection specific data here...
    };
}];
```

The collection specific data structure for `data_invoices` is:

```
number: number;
amount: number;
```

The collection specific data structure for `data_jobs` is:

```
name: string;
```

The structure of the data_links table is:

```
createdOn: number;
replacedOn?: number; // though I don't have any records with this value set
```

The `createdOn` field is the date value represented as ticks from 1970, and is a random date from 01 Jan 2000 to today.

The `amount` field is a random currency value (2 decimal places) from 10 to 10,000.

The `number` field is an autonumber type field.

I have two very similar (in my opinion) queries, one way (jobs to invoices) works very, very quickly, the other one takes ages.

This query takes 1.85 seconds:

```
LET date = 1495616898128

FOR job IN data_jobs
    FILTER job.tenantId IN ['xxx', 'yyy']
    FILTER job.createdOn<=date
    LET jobData = (job.data[* FILTER CURRENT.createdOn<=date LIMIT 1])[0]
    FILTER CONTAINS(jobData.values.name, 'a')
    LET invoices = (
        FOR invoice, link IN 1 INBOUND job data_links
            FILTER link.createdOn<=date AND (link.replacedOn == NULL OR
                link.replacedOn>date)
            LET invoiceData = (invoice.data[* FILTER CURRENT.createdOn<=date LIMIT 1])[0]
            FILTER invoiceData.values.amount>1000
            COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO count
            RETURN {
                count 
            }
    )[0]
    FILTER invoices.count>0
    SORT jobData.values.name ASC
    LIMIT 0,8
    RETURN job
```

This query takes 8.5 seconds:

```
LET date = 1495616898128

FOR invoice IN data_invoices
    FILTER invoice.tenantId IN ['xxx', 'yyy']
    FILTER invoice.createdOn<=date
    LET invoiceData = (invoice.data[* FILTER CURRENT.createdOn<=date LIMIT 1])[0]
    FILTER invoiceData.values.amount>1000
    LET jobs = (
        FOR job, link IN 1 OUTBOUND invoice data_links
            FILTER link.createdOn<=date AND (link.replacedOn == NULL 
                OR link.replacedOn>date)
            LET jobData = (job.data[* FILTER CURRENT.createdOn<=date LIMIT 1])[0]
            FILTER CONTAINS(jobData.values.name, 'a')
            COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO count
            RETURN {
                count 
            } 
    )[0]
    FILTER jobs.count>0
    SORT invoiceData.values.amount ASC
    LIMIT 0,8
    RETURN invoice
```

I realise that both queries are providing different data, but the processing time should be the same shouldn't it?  They are both filtering both tables through the links table and both performing aggregations on the other.  I don't understand why one way is much quicker than the other way.  Is there anything I can do to increase the performance of these queries please?

Comment: In `data_jobs`, you have filter conditions on two attributes at the same time, `tenantId` and `createdOn`. How performant is your query if you create a persistent index on both, so define it as `tenantId, createdOn`. Multi attribute indexes can really help, especially when you're using both in same query.

Comment: Thank you @DavidThomas I will give that a go, but like I said, those filters don't actually take any records away (deliberately - I am worst case scenario testing), and whilst they may speed up the query having them as a single index, I doubt it will be much - I will definitely give it a go though.

Comment: Post a comment on what you find. With tweaking I had one query that took 124 seconds go down to 0.2 seconds. They key for me was multi column indexes and building your queries so that the AQL engine could easily determine what index to use.

Comment: I have added the persistent multi-column index suggested to both the `data_invoices` collection and the `data_jobs` collection and it has made no difference at all.  What I have found out though is that the time taken seems to all be in the sort, when I remove the sort, it takes 2.5 ms.  So I decided to add an index to the amount field (which was added as `data[*].values.amount` as that is where it lives inside the collection.  It unfortunately was not used and made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, strange but I have stumbled upon a very counter-intuitive (at least to me) solution.  Sort first, then filter...???

This query now takes 1.4 seconds:

```
LET date = 1495616898128

FOR invoice IN data_invoices
    FILTER invoice.tenantId IN ['xxx', 'yyy']
    FILTER invoice.createdOn<=date
    LET invoiceData = (invoice.data[* FILTER CURRENT.createdOn<=date LIMIT 1])[0]
    SORT invoiceData.values.amount ASC
    FILTER invoiceData.values.amount>1000
    LET jobs = (
        FOR job, link IN 1 OUTBOUND invoice data_links
            FILTER link.createdOn<=date AND (link.replacedOn == NULL 
                OR link.replacedOn>date)
            LET jobData = (job.data[* FILTER CURRENT.createdOn<=date LIMIT 1])[0]
            FILTER CONTAINS(jobData.values.name, 'a')
            COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO count
            RETURN {
                count 
            } 
    )[0]
    FILTER jobs.count>0        
    LIMIT 0,8
    RETURN invoice
```

Despite adding a persistent index on `data[*].values.amount`, it still does not use it (I even tried `SORT invoice.data[0].values.amount ASC` and it still didn't seem to use the index?)

Can anyone explain this please?